# LESS Outputs extra semicolon

Tags: javascript, css, less, codekit

I have an advanced mixin() that I am attempting to debug. I use CodeKit as my compiler and I keep getting strange output.

**Here is the mixin():**

```
.push(@arr, @tag, @prop, @value){
    -lessMinded:@arr~`api.push(@{arr}, @{tag}, @{prop}, @{value})`
}

.media(@arr){
    -lessMinded:@arr~`api.media(@{arr})`
}
```

**Here is the JavaScript that helps process the mixin():**

```
@api:`function(){
    var api = {
        tablet: [],
        push:function(arr, tag, prop, value){
            var str = "";

            str = tag+"{ "+prop+":"+value+" }"
            this[arr].push(str);
        },
        media:function(arr){
            var count = this[arr].length,
                values = "";
            for(var i = 0; i < count; ++i){
                values += this[arr][i]+"\n";
            };
            values = values.substring(0, values.length-1);
            return "; "+values;
        }
    };
    return(api);
}`;

@apiGlobalInjector: `(function() {
    this.api = (@{api})();
    return("LessMinded.com global helper functions");
})()`;
```

**Usage within the LESS CSS Sheet:**

```
body{
    content:"in stylesheet";
    .push("tablet", "body", "padding", "30px")
}
nav{
    .push("tablet", "nav", "margin", "10px")
}
ul{
    .push("tablet", "ul", "margin", "10px")
}
li{
    .push("tablet", "li", "margin", "10px")
}
p{
    .push("tablet", "p", "margin", "10px")
}
a{
    .push("tablet", "a", "margin", "10px")
}

@media only screen and (max-width:1025px){
    .media("tablet")
}
```

**Here is the output:**

```
body {
  content: "in stylesheet";
  -lessMinded: "tablet" ;
}
nav {
  -lessMinded: "tablet" ;
}
ul {
  -lessMinded: "tablet" ;
}
li {
  -lessMinded: "tablet" ;
}
p {
  -lessMinded: "tablet" ;
}
a {
  -lessMinded: "tablet" ;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 1025px) {
    -lessMinded: "tablet" ; body{ padding:30px }
    nav{ margin:10px }
    ul{ margin:10px }
    li{ margin:10px }
    p{ margin:10px }
    a{ margin:10px };
}
```

**Overall:**

I am aware that the "-lessMinded" property is rendered regardless, this is a known issue when working with LESS in this manor. This is not the error.

The error is the extra semicolon within the media query at the last element `a{ margin:10px };`

In a dream world I would like to not have to pass in the element as well, but I know there is no way to pre-read the selectors.

```
body{
          //array    tag     property   value
    .push("tablet", "body", "padding", "30px");
}
```

Comment: Are you one of the LessMinded devs? Looks interesting but also waaay heavier than just writing out that final media query ;)

Comment: Yes I am and I definitely agree with you, but how cool would it be to store all CSS for the element in one location and let the compiler handle the rest.

Comment: For sure, I write a lot of `element { property: value; @media (max-width: ... ) {property2: value2} @media (max-width: ...) {property3: value3} }`. Interested to see where LessMinded goes! Don't see where the semicolon's coming from though, sorry

Comment: I'm beginning to think it is the CodeKit compiler it's self. I will thread them in on their message board and see if they have any ideas on how I might be able to modify the .codeKit file it's self. Even tho that is a poor life decision. :)

Comment: It isn't just CodeKit. Here's a pen - if you "view compiled CSS" you see the same thing.  Codepen's debugger is also throwing `JavaScript evaluation error: 'ReferenceError: api is not defined'` at the end of the `body` style http://codepen.io/henry/pen/ozgqOr?editors=0110#

Comment: Yea I attempted to use all the compilers I could get my hands on and they all throw other errors saying api is not defined or value is null.

The closest I got was Koala's compiler but I would have to rewrite the JavaScript to a really really messy variation just to get it through. I may spend next weekend attempting that but until then I will see if there is anything down this road worth investigating.

Comment: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NRPrqx?editors=0100#0

I moved the JS over to the LESS side and it does the same thing.

Comment: https://github.com/less/less.js/issues/2959 Posted to the LESS language bugs portal in light of the new code pen. @henry Thanks for extra effort!